# Javascript/Node.js - How to properly wait for asynchronous function to return a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, node-modules

I'm having trouble understanding asynchronous programming in node.js. I've read multiple articles, but I still get it wrong when using async/await in my own code.

I'm making a web scraper node.js module.

Here is a sample of the async/await usage in my node.js module:

```
async function scrape(url, ports) {
  const randomPort = options.ports[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.ports.length)];

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:' + randomPort],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
      if (['image', 'stylesheet', 'font', 'script'].indexOf(request.resourceType()) !== -1) {
          request.abort();
      } else {
          request.continue();
      }
  });
  
  await page.goto(url);
  const content = await page.content();
  const livetable = parse_body(content);

  setTimeout(() => {
    browser.close();
  }, 3000);

  return livetable;
}

exports.get_livetable = async function(options) {
  // code for handling the options, create the 
  var data = await scrape(url);
  return data;
}
```

Sample of how I use the module in my other code

```
var livetable = myNodeJSModule.get_livetable(options);
console.log(livetable);
```

If I log the data like this, the node module returns an empty result - it doesn't wait for the web scraper function to finish its work. How can I make the get_livetable function to wait for the scrape function to finish executing?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is that `exports.get_livetable` is asynchronous in itself, which means you will have to await it as well. I would suggest using `then` instead, like this: `myNodeJSModule.get_livetable(options).then(function(livetable) {/*Do something...*/ console.log(livetable);})`

Comment: Please post the implementation of scrape method as it could potentially be a culprit.

Comment: `var livetable = await myNodeJSModule.get_livetable(options)`

Comment: I included the implementation of the scrape method. I cannot use await myNodeJSModule because it's not inside an await function.

Comment: @lukasrajnoha You'll have to put it one then. Or use `.then(livetable => { … })` instead of  `await`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an async IIFE or the `then` handler.

The first is to create an async function and call it immediately:

```
(async () => {
   // await works here
   var livetable = await myNodeJSModule.get_livetable(options)
})();
```

Or use the `then` to register a callback when the result is ready:

```
myNodeJSModule.get_livetable(options).then((livetable) => {
  // process the result
})
```